# Bash - Comparing 2 xml strings masking certain fields

Tags: xml, bash, sed

Would like to compare 2 XML Strings which has certain known fields changed. For example, Date field will always have differences. When comparing both strings, skip/mask all the occurring Date Field's `DtField1` and `DtField2`

Note: these are not formatted xml format.

File1:

```
<Field1><Field2><Field5></Field5><DtField1>Jan 01 2017,00:00:01</DtField1><Code>052</Code><Desc>This is a test</Desc><DtField2>Jan 01 2001,00:00:26</DtField2><Field4>Company</Field4><Field6></Field6></Field3></Field2></Field1>
```

File2:

```
<Field1><Field2><Field5></Field5><DtField1>Jan 01 2017,00:00:01</DtField1><Code>052</Code><Desc>This is a test</Desc><DtField2>Jan 01 2001,00:00:39</DtField2><Field4>Company</Field4><Field6></Field6></Field3></Field2></Field1>
```

I have tried to sed the string into blocks using the code

```
Block1=`sed -n 's:.*<Field1>\(.*\)</Field5>.*:\1:p' File`
Block2=`sed -n 's:.*<Code>\(.*\)</Desc>.*:\1:p' File`
Block3=`sed -n 's:.*<Field4>\(.*\)</Field1>.*:\1:p' File`
```

and compare the Blocks of File1 with File2 but there is a possibility that Fields may not be in order every time. However, fields will be in same position in String1 and String2.

So, it is easy to somehow mask/remove the occurring DtField's and compare 2 strings.

Expected Output:

```
<Field1><Field2><Field5></Field5><Code>052</Code><Desc>This is a test</Desc><Field4>Company</Field4><Field6></Field6></Field3></Field2></Field1>
```

Comment: Use a proper XML tool (not `sed`!) to normalize the two streams so they have a well-defined field order and predictable variations are stripped or replaced 'ith standard values.

Comment: Well, are the strings valid XML or not? Your samples are not.

Comment: You can't call something XML and then say it isn't. Please update with real XML or say at least exactly what differences you are looking for (not what you're *not* looking for).

Comment: Are you open to using Perl (or some other language) that can more easily handle XML?

Comment: @tale: perl works too

Comment: content pasted in the File section, is the content of the file. its not specific XML format, however, it works with the tags.

I have included expected output as well.